# Using Firebase for a project

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to start using Firebase for my project, in short what do I need to know to get started. Will SQL be a better choice for a project that is small but will store user information like log-in credentials and account information. However, i got kind of confused when i found out there is 'Realtime Database' and 'Cloud Firestore'. Is firebase something seperate, or are these 2 just different versions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to look at it is, to view firebase as the entire 'backend as a service' and view Cloud Functions, Hosting, Firestore, Auth, etc as it's individual backend services. You could theoretically have your entire app run off of firebase server-lessly (whether or not that's cost efficient is another story), but most people I have spoken with that have used Firebase take bits and pieces to optimize and supplement their current architecture.

I can't speak on firebase's realtime db, but I have used Firestore quite a bit. I think the main difference is the data structure. Firestore uses a collection/document/sub-collection structure so it's pretty awesome in term's of keeping your data nice and organized. If you're looking to use Firestore, you should definitley take some time to learn how to build out and deploy google cloud functions to extend your firestore's functionality.